# Asp.Net Core - How to set the UrlAction in Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an input box to search ...

Html :

```
<form id="searchForm" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="SearchProduct" method="get">
```

This input performs search in two ways:

1- After pressing the Enter key
2- After the click on the "a" tag

In the first step, the address is displayed in the image below :
[image]

In the second step, the address is displayed in the image below :
[image]

After searching again, the address is displayed in the image below
[image]

JavaScript :

```
 $('.txt-search-story').click(function () {
    var span = $(this).find('span');
    var txtspan = span.text();

     $.ajax({
         url: "/Product/GetTextSearch",
         type: 'Get',
         data: { "q": txtspan },
         success: function (response) {
             window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
         }
    });
});
```

Controller one :

```
[Route("/search/{**q}")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchProduct(string q, int page = 1)
    {
        if (q != null)
        {                
            var searchProduct = await _product.SearchProduct(q, skip, countproduct);
            ViewBag.searchtext = q;

            return View(searchProduct);
        }                    
    }
```

Controller two for Ajax:

```
 public IActionResult GetTextSearch(string q)
    {
        return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("SearchProduct", "Product", new { q = q }) });
    }
```

I want the second address to be like the first address What should I do?

Comment: remove /{**q} from route it will create query ...?q=a ?

Answer (score 1):

thanks @daremachine -
I changed [Route("/search/{**q}")]

to

[Route("/search")]

it's worked